# Cosmos db internal data representation for mongoose client

Tags: azure, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

When I insert items in collection using mongoose client and later access it via portal ui I can see that internal representation is not what I am expected.

Here is how I save data

```
      var db = mongoose.createConnection(mongodbURL)
      var Model = db.model('Model', require('./models/model.js'))

      var insert = q.nbind(Model.insertMany, Model)

      insert([ .... , {
          _id: "something like 58ef14c7f0f3ee5ef88796c3",
          name: "NAME" 
      }]
```

Here is what I get in Azure query explorer

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$t": 7,
    "$v": "Xï\u0014Çðóî^øÃ"
  },
  "name": {
    "$t": 2,
    "$v": "NAME"
  },
  ...........

 },
 ................
```

And this is my expectations

```
{
  "_id": "58ef14c7f0f3ee5ef88796c3",
  "name": "NAME"
  ...........

 },
 ................
```

Have I missed something? Thanks.

Comment: That looks like some corrupt data. Perhaps edit your question to show your model, and the query you're running which retrieves that data?

Answer (score -1):

Please use Data Explorer - it will show your data correctly. Query Explorer is a legacy tool and is going away, at least for MongoDB API accounts.